# Duplicate line in text file

Tags: python

Say I have an `"input.txt`" file:

> abcabc
> aaabbb
> cccddd

I want to duplicate each line to this:

> abcabcabcabc
> aaabbbaaabbb
> cccdddcccddd

and read it into a list.

I tried doing this:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:

    input_test = []

    for line in f:

        input_test.append(line)*2
```

but it only duplicates the last line which is:

```
abcabc 
aaabbb 
cccdddcccddd
```

Comment: Please demonstrate what you have tried thus far

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure the trailing newline character is removed from `line`, as currently `line` is going to contain something like "cccdddcccddd\n" ("\n" is the newline character), so multiplying it would produce 2 lines. You can remove the trailing newline character using the `rstrip` method:

```py
line = line.rstrip()
```

Then, do `input_test.append(line*2)` instead of `input_test.append(line)*2` to multiply the line before appending it. Right now you're multiplying the result of `append` which should actually raise a `TypeError` because `append` always returns `None`.

Comment: That won't work, due to embedded newlines in the output.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks for the note, I've made an update.